# How do i make a countdown with Hours, Minutes and Seconds, set for a certain time.

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a count down timer. This is what i have so far.

```
var now = new Date();
var then = now.getHours();    
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = now - then;
```

when i subtract `now-then` i get a bunch of numbers. How do i make it so when i set the exact date and time(with seconds) it will give me the outcome?

Comment: yes, you can `<input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?> ">`

Comment: @carlos what are you asking in your second question. Could you explain briefly?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know if they were the same; I guess what I am trying to say is this: Can I call the id from the `input` attribute, and call it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `php` code must always be used in these `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>`. And you have two solutions for your issue.

**Method 1:** By using `<?php ?>` tag:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
```

**Method 2:** By using `<?= ?>` tag directly accessing variables:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="<?= $name ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks alot!This cleared some things i did not quite understand!

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen anytime :)

Comment: short open tags <? and ?> are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it like this

```
<?php

$name = "jack";
?>
<input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $name = "jack";
    echo "<input type='text' id='name' value='{$name}'>";
?>
```

Comment: Could i type php in brackets? Wow, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's posible, like this.

```
<?php

$name = "jack";

?>
<input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
```

or

```
$name = "jack";
print "<input type='text' id='name' value='$name' />";

?>
```

If you need something else, add comment and I edit with more information

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
<?php
   $name = "jack";
?>
<input type="text" id="name" value="<?= $name ?>">
```

Comment: I cant vote up, but, if i could, i would! Thanks for your help!